# read geojson file which is not in CRS 4326

Tags: r, geojson

I have a geojson file which i need to read/convert to sf object

I read it with geojsonR package and it shows as lists of lists, but i need it to sf. I tried using st_read but it gives me "Error: dsn must point to a source, not an empty string."

Also tried geojsonsf package and geojson_sf() and it gives me "Error in rcpp_geojson_to_sf(geojson, expand_geometries) : Invalid JSON"

how can i read it as sf and more importantly - i need sf geometry from there...

The file is here https://vustaff-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/e5028514_vu_edu_au/ERKzUBrFobBKrNe7ga-3arMB63ZuyD4eDbAtPQ5fzy2BbQ?e=m87Af9

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the CRS is a problem here. Although the geojson spec says "only use epsg:4326" there is a paragraph in the spec where it grudgingly concedes that if two people agree to use something else then oh go on then use that.

The problem appears to be complexity. Testing with `ogrinfo` produces over a 1000 of these:

```
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex, please see the OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE environment option
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex, please see the OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE environment option
```

Reading in R using `st_read` took a long time, and I interrupted it and a large number of those warnings were revealed by `warnings()`. I couldn't replicate your error but maybe I didn't leave it long enough. Note I'm using:

```
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

and GDAL version may be important here.

Setting the environment variable mentioned in the error to a large value on the command line then works:

```
$ export OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE=10000
$ ogrinfo -so -al test.geojson
INFO: Open of `test.geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: grunnkretser.delomradegrense
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 10284
```

What I'd personally do is then convert the geoJson to a geopackage:

```
$ export OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE=10000
$ ogr2ogr test.gpkg test.geojson
```

which will then read into R much quicker. The data appears to be multiple layers, which you can read individually into R objects:

```
pol = st_read("./test.gpkg","grunnkretser.grunnkrets")
plot(pol[,"kommunenummer"], border=FALSE)
```

[image]

You can use `st_layers("test.gpkg")` to get the layer names.

If you can set that environment variable such that R runs with it set, then you can use the usual `sf` functions and they should cope. But it will be a lot slower than reading from a geoPackage.

```
> pol = st_read("./test.geojson","grunnkretser.grunnkrets")
Reading layer `grunnkretser.grunnkrets' from data source 
  `/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/test.geojson' using driver `GeoJSON'
Simple feature collection with 14106 features and 12 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 4000785 ymin: 3853251 xmax: 5133868 ymax: 5438387
Projected CRS: ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe
```

That takes about 20 seconds, compared with 0.2seconds for the geopackage read of the same data (100x faster!). Ideally someone should never have created this as geoJson in the first place!